# Does the stop opt code cause a revert?

Tags: evm

Does the stop opt code revert the transaction?  What is the point of the stop opt code?
I am unclear why the stop opt code is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stop opcode halts the execution but it does not revert the transaction

from the [ethereum yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf):

[image]

you can check it debugging any transaction using remix at the end you will find always the stop opcode:

[image]